# return a 2 dimentional int matrix in java

Tags: java, eclipse, matrix, methods, return

I am working on a code for class. It involved two dimensional int arrays that represent matrices. I am trying to write a method that returns a new Matrix after it adds two together. Here is my method:

```
    public Matrix plus(Matrix other)
{
    Matrix temp=new int[other.getRows()][other.getColumns()];
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            setElement(i, j, this.getElement(i, j)+other.getElement(i, j));
        }
    }
        return temp;
}
```

and here is the two parameter constructor that is called:

```
    public Matrix(int r, int c)
{
    row=r;
    column=c;
    mtrx=new int[row][column];
}
```

I am getting an error on the return statement.

Here is my JUnit test:

```
    public void testPlus() {
    Matrix m1 = zero3x3.plus(one3x3);       
    assertEquals(one3x3.toString(), m1.toString());

    Matrix m2 = ident3x3.plus(one3x3);
    assertEquals("2 1 1\n1 2 1\n1 1 2\n", m2.toString());

    Matrix m3 = rowPlusCol3x4.plus(rowPlusCol3x4);
    assertEquals("0 2 4 6\n2 4 6 8\n4 6 8 10\n", m3.toString());

}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information to help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure about `Matrix temp=new int[other.getRows()][other.getColumns()];` ? Shouldn't this be `Matrix temp = new Matrix(other.getRows(), other.getColumns())` ?

Comment: Also, you might want to add a condition that verifies that the matrices you are trying to add have the same dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected that statement. I will add another test. I am now having another problem in the logical error process where the set element is not working properly. How can I reference the object that called the method? Example: matrix1.plus(matrix2); How do I access matrix1 to add it to matrix2 in the method?

Comment: use your variable mtrx for matrix 1